# How do I add all my Amazon Kindle purchases to Goodreads?

Tags: amazon, export, goodreads

My ultimate goal is to export a list of my Kindle purchase history. It doesn't look like that is possible on Amazon's site. Amazon has an integration with Goodreads and Goodreads allows you to export your information.

http://www.goodreads.com/amazon_purchases

The problem is that you have to click on every book to add it to Goodreads. I'm pretty lazy. Is there a faster way through maybe a script to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I found the button class for the 'Want to Read' button and looped through and clicked them all by running this Javascript in the console.

```
var buttonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('w-button-common w-button-unfollow'); for(var a=0;a<buttonArray.length;a++){ buttonArray[a].click(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the JavaScript [you included](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88692/21583) but got an error. However I was able to leverage your approach using:

```
var buttonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('wtrToRead'); 
for (var a = 0; a < buttonArray.length; a++) {
  buttonArray[a].click();
}
```

Looks like the button names may have changed.